# How to make dynamic animation with ObjectAnimator?

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, animation

I'm currently working in a custom view, basically its a draggable view that has a pulse effect. In fact I achieved the effect that I want but I it has performance issues.

[image]

I don't know if it can be seen well in the gif but at first the effect runs without problems and then it shows performance issues.

Here is my class

```kotlin
class BalanceAndFadeView @JvmOverloads constructor(...) : FrameLayout(...) {

    // The thumb view is the draggable view
    private var thumb: ImageView

    // These are for the pulsing effect
    private var pulseView: ImageView
    private var pulseView2: ImageView

    private var selectedPoint: Point = Point()

    private val animators = arrayListOf<Animator>()
    private var animatorsSet = AnimatorSet()

    private var centerX = 0f
    private var centerY = 0f

    init {
        // Here I create and add the views to the root view
    }

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) { 
        centerX = w * 0.5f
        centerY = h * 0.5f
        animationStart()
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return when (event.actionMasked) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                val snapPoint = Point(event.x.toInt(), event.y.toInt())
                selectedPoint = snapPoint
                setCoordinate(snapPoint.x, snapPoint.y)
                true
            }
            else -> {
                false
            }
        }

    }


    fun setCoordinate(x: Int, y: Int) {
        // Sets the thumb view coordinates to create the draggable view effect
        thumb.x = x - thumb.measuredWidth * 0.5f
        thumb.y = y - thumb.measuredHeight * 0.5f

        // These animators are for the pulsing effect to translate to the center of the view
        // I want the start point of the translation to update with the position 
        // of the thumb view, so I need it to be a dynamic animation
        val translationXAnimator =
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(pulseView, "TranslationX", x.toFloat() - centerX, 0f)
                .apply {
                    repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE
                    repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.RESTART
                    startDelay = 0
                }

        val translationYAnimator =
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(pulseView, "TranslationY", y.toFloat() - centerY, 0f)
                .apply {
                    repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE
                    repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.RESTART
                    startDelay = 0
                }

        val translationXAnimator2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(...).apply { ... }

        val translationYAnimator2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(...).apply { ... }

        animatorsSet.playTogether(
            ... // adds new animators
        )

        // Since I run this method every time the touch event it's troggered, 
        // the performance gets worse every time I touch the screen

        animatorsSet.start()

        // But if I call animatorsSet.end() and then animatorsSet.start()
        // the pulsing effect does not work as expected since the animation stops
        // but in terms of performance it's just normal

    }


    // These animators are for the pulsing effect

    private fun animationStart() {

        val scaleXAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(pulseView, "ScaleX", 1f, 6f).apply {
            repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE
            repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.RESTART
            startDelay = 0
        }

        animators.add(scaleXAnimator)

        val scaleYAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(pulseView, "ScaleY", 1f, 6f).apply {
            repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE
            repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.RESTART
            startDelay = 0
        }

        animators.add(scaleYAnimator)

        val alphaAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(pulseView, "Alpha", 1f, 0f).apply {
            repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE
            repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.RESTART
            startDelay = 0
        }

        animators.add(alphaAnimator)

        val scaleXAnimator2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat( ... ).apply { ... }
        animators.add(scaleXAnimator2)

        val scaleYAnimator2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat( ... ).apply { ... }
        animators.add(scaleYAnimator2)

        val alphaAnimator2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat( ... ).apply { ... }
        animators.add(alphaAnimator2)

        animatorsSet.playTogether(animators)
        animatorsSet.interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
        animatorsSet.duration = 1000
        animatorsSet.start()

    }
    
}
```

I hope you can help me or recommend me a better approach

Comment: Are you ever clearing your animators list? It seems from the code posted an ever growing list of animators could be causing performance issues.

Comment: Oh you are rigth, when I print animatorsSet.childAnimations.size, I get a bigger number everytime, but how can I clear the animations in the animatiorsSet?  The only way i see to do this, is by calling animatorsSet.cancel() and it restarts my animations everytime :c